# How to close Submenu when clicking on another menu link in twig

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a vertical menu in twig (Symfony2). Some menu links have submenus. The parent li of the submenu is also a href. For example:

```
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul id="myMenu">
    <li class="has-sub">
      <a href="{{ path(entity.route) }}">
        <span>Dashboard</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub">
     <a href="{{ path(entity.route) }}">
       <span>Statistic</span>
     </a>
       <ul class="sub">
         <li> 
           <a href="{{ path(menue.route) }}">
             <span class="subMenu">Statistic1</span>
           </a>
          </li>
          <li> 
            <a href="{{ path(menue.route) }}">
              <span class="subMenu">Statistic2</span>
            </a>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to click on the Statistic-menu and to be forwarded to the general Statistic page and at the same time I want the submenu of the Statistic to be opened and stay opened as long as I am on the Statistic page. When I click on Statistic1 or Statistic 2 in the submenu I should be forwarded to their respective pages. The submenu should stay opened in this cases. 
When I click on Dashboard I want to be forwarded to the Dashboard page and to have the Statistic submenu closed.

At the moment, when I click on Dashboard the Statistic submenu stays opened too.

Here is the script I use:

```
$(function() {
 $('#myMenu > li').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   var $el = $('ul',this);
   $('#myMenu > li > ul').not($el).slideUp();
   $el.stop(true, true).slideToggle(400);
 });
$('#myMenu > li > ul > li').click(function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();  
  });
});
```

I have a suspicion that the page is being loaded together with the menu. It is symfony and I have a base.html.twig, which includes the menu. Each of the templates extends base.html.twig.

I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: Your title suggests a javascript solution to close one dropdown when another is opened. But your question suggests you may want to add a classname to the href that's active. Which is it? Or is it both?

Comment: I am open to everything but I asume it can only be solved with javascript/jquery

Comment: But I still don't know what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, How can I get the submenu closed when I click on another link in the menu in my example, which I described above?